# Javascript Determine if page was refreshed or redirected from another page?

Tags: javascript, redirect

The question is pretty much in title.

Is there a way in Javascript to determine whether the page has been refreshed by user or loaded after redirecting from other website?

Comment: Try checking `document.referrer`.

Comment: You can try by checking request referer. It tells you who referred you to this page. If the referrer is same - Refresh else redirect

Comment: that's not accurate if you try refreshing this page and use document.referrer it will tell you its http://stackoverflow.com/ not the complete url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`performance.navigation.type` will tell you if the page was reloaded, and some more info.  Check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a straight answer, as the answer above says you should

> console.log(window.performance.navigation.type)

to see if the page was reloaded or redirected. 1 = reloaded and 0 = redirected.